# Selenium How to not fail a test if element not exist (java)

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to pass a test where an element does not exist (due to user access),
then it will be written to extent report,
but I keep getting "no such element exception".

My code is like this:

```
if (homePage.cloudAdminApp.isDisplayed())
{
    test.log(LogStatus.PASS, getData("USER") +" have  o/cloud admin application access but it shoudn't have");
}
else 
{
    test.log(LogStatus.PASS, getData("USER") +" have not o/cloud admin application access");
}
```

I also tried to do:

- add `try` and `catch (NoSuchElementException e)` but the test keep failing.
- add instead of the `if` an `Assert.assertNull`

None have worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where you did use `try``catch` ?

Comment: i moved it since it not worked out. it used to have try& catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no element on Web Page `findElement` will return `NoSuchElementException`

and `FindElements` will returns empty list so you can try this way

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.locator);

if(elements.size()>0)
{
    elements.get(0).click()
}
```

And the other way is enclose your code properly in try catch block

e.g.

```
try
{
       driver.findElement(By.locator).click();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   System.out.println("No Element");
   // write your code here for action have to do if element is not there
}
```

Comment: i used it and now i get the "Null Pointer Exception"

Comment: Then its your diver instance issue. Have you initialized the driver ?

Comment: yea you right. when i editing my code several times i probably removed some lines. thanks it now worked!

Answer (score 0):

we can use findelements to check the presence of an element without using try/catch. Its simple too. Below code might give you some idea,

```
if(driver.findElements(By.id(CLOUDADMINAPP)).size>0)
{
    //Element is present now
    //Do the Stuff
}else
{
    //Element is not present
    //Do the stuff
}
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: i used it and now i get the "Null Pointer Exception"

Comment: which line throws this exception?

Comment: yea you right. when i editing my code several times i probably removed some lines. thanks it now worked!